# Google Maps heat map and markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Im trying to set up a heat map (which i did) but seems that google integrates all the markers in one point and if i zoom in it still showing only one point.

Using heat map:

[image]

Using Markers:

[image]

as you can see i got all my markers grouped in the center wich is cool but thats not what i expected...

Is there any way to avoid "markers grouping" ?

Comment: In the second image the markers are not groupe ... check for the real lat/lng ..

Comment: @scaisEdge what you mean by `real lat/lng` ?

Comment: I mean that the markers seem correct positioned (not grouped)  when grouped they are all in the same location ..

Comment: @scaisEdge maybe i didnt express myself good and the issue is that when i use heatmap layer they all group in 1 point. Thats what i want, to have them all positioned (not grouped)

Comment: show the related code .. please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the heatmap with some parameters ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/heatmaplayer#customize_a_heatmap_layer)). You may want to tweak the `dissipating` and `radius` parameters:

> **dissipating:** Specifies whether heatmaps dissipate on zoom. When dissipating is false the radius of influence increases with zoom level to ensure that the color intensity is preserved at any given geographic location. Defaults to false.
>
> **radius:** The radius of influence for each data point, in pixels.